# 2 Inputs via command line of python and "if __name__ == "__main__":"

Tags: python

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

I have working the following code:

```
            else:
                stack_queue.append((next, edge + [next]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(breath_first_search(graph, 'J', 'A')))
```

It prints on Spyder console "[['J', 'I', 'H', 'C', 'A']]"

I would like to run this via cmd. I am doing this way:

```
python C:\XX\XX-first-search.py
```

It is also giving me the correct result.

Now, I would like to change this to receive, from the cmd, the 2 letters of input. I tried:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(breath_first_search(graph, sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1])))
```

It gives me the error:
[image: error of my first try]

I also tried:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(breath_first_search(graph, sys.argv, sys.argv)))
```

[image]

If you need, my whole code:

```
import sys

graph = {'A': set(['B', 'C']),
         'B': set(['A', 'D', 'E']),
         'C': set(['A', 'G', 'H']),
         'D': set(['B']),
         'E': set(['B', 'F']),
         'F': set(['E']),
         'G': set(['C']),
         'H': set(['C','I']),
         'I': set(['H', 'J']),
         'J': set(['I'])}


def breath_first_search(graph, initial_node, final_node):
    stack_queue = [(initial_node, [initial_node])]  # List; initial node is the initial node; creates a list 

    while stack_queue:
        (node, edge) = stack_queue.pop(0)

        for next in graph[node] - set(edge):

            if next == final_node:
                yield edge + [next]

            else:
                stack_queue.append((next, edge + [next]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(breath_first_search(graph, sys.argv, sys.argv)))
```

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is the program name itself. You want to start from `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you answer correctly and first. If you put yours as an answer, I can tag as correct.

Comment: First is not so important as best; Willem's answer is quite well-written. I won't be slighted in the least if you accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`sys.argv`** [doc]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) is a the list of parameters passed to the program, *including* the program itself as first parameter (so `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the program).

We thus can use `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` to pass the two extra parameters:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(breath_first_search(graph, sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])))
```

Or we can first do some proper checking and *sequence unpacking* to make it more elegant:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print('Program requires two parameters')
        sys.exit(1)
    __, a, b = sys.argv
    print(list(breath_first_search(graph, a, b)))
```